# How to use variables inside single quotes

Tags: shell, quoting, variable

I have an application which takes as an input attributes in double quotes embedded in single quotes. Take for example this right command:

```
command -p 'cluster="cl1"'
```

In order to automate it, I created a bash file using `$CLUSTER` as a variable.
How should be my command? In other words, what should I put instead of cl1?

Please note that, If I modified the above command, it won't be accepted. For instance: `command -p "cluster=cl1"` is not accepted

Comment: `CLUSTER='"cl1"'; command -p "cluster=$CLUSTER"`

Comment: Another possibility (if you prefer to store `cli` without quotes inside `CLUSTER` variable): `CLUSTER='cl1'; command -p 'cluster="'"$CLUSTER"'"'`

Comment: Finally, I found the right answer. Thanks @jimmij.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like your command is maybe setting environment variables based on arguments given it on the command-line. It may be you can do:

```
CLUSTER=cl1; cluster=$CLUSTER command
```

...and set its environment for it at invocation.

Otherwise, shell quotes typically delimit arguments or escape other special shell characters from shell interpretation. You can contain *(and therefore escape)* different kinds of shell-quotes within other kinds based on various rules:

- `"''''"` - a soft-quoted string can contain any number of hard-quotes.
- `"\""` - a `\` backslash can escape a `"`soft-quote within a `"`soft-quoted string.

  - In this context a `\\`backslash also escapes itself, the `\$`expansion token, and `\n`ewlines as noted below, but is otherwise treated literally.
- `"${expand} and then some"` - a soft-quoted string can contain an interpreted shell `$`expansion.
- `'"\'` - a `'`hard-quoted string can contain any character other than a `'`hard-quote.
- `\` - an unquoted backslash will escape any following character for literal interpretation - even another backslash - excepting a `\n`ewline.

  - In a `\\n`ewline case both the `\` backslash and the `\n`ewline are completely removed from the resulting interpreted command.
- `${parameter+expand "$parameter"}` - quotes resulting from a shell expansion almost never serve as delimiter markers excepting a few special cases. I won't venture to describe these further here.

I consider it odd that any application would interpret quotes in its command-line args. Such a practice doesn't make a lot of sense in that - for shells, at least - the primary purpose of a quote is generally to delimit an argument. At invocation, however, arguments are always *already delimited* with `\0NUL` characters and so a quote cannot serve much purpose.

Even a shell will typically only bother to interpret quotes in one of its invocation arguments when it is called with a `-c` switch - which denotes that its first *operand* is actually a shell script that it should run upon invocation. This is a case of *twice evaluated* input.

All that said, you can do a number of things to pass literal quotes via arguments on the command-line. For example:

```
CLUSTER='"cl1"'; command -p "cluster=$CLUSTER"
```

As I noted in a comment before, you can contain the `"` quotes within an expansion that is itself `"` quoted.

```
CLUSTER=cl1; command -p "cluster=\"$CLUSTER\""
```

You can escape the `"` with a `\`backslash within the `"` quoted string.

```
CLUSTER=cl1; command -p cluster='"'"$CLUSTER"'"'
```

You can alternate and concatenate quoting styles to arrive at your desired end result as @jimmij [notes above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178411/how-to-use-variables-inside-single-quotes#comment296396_178411).

```
CLUSTER=cl1; ( set -f; IFS=; command -p cluster=\"$CLUSTER\" )
```

You can disable both *file name generation* and `$IFS` splitting - thereby avoiding the need to quote the `$expansion` at all - and so only quote the quotes. This is probably overkill.

Last, there is another type of shell-quote that might be used. As I noted before the `sh -c "$scriptlet"` form of shell invocation is often used to provide a shell's script on the command-line. When `$scriptlet` gets complicated though - such as when quotes must contain other quotes - it can often be advantageous to use a here-document and `sh -s` instead - where the shell is specifically instructed to assign all following *operands* to the positional parameters as it would do in a `-c` case and yet to also take its script from `stdin`.

If your command must interpret quotes in this way then I would consider it better if it could do so in a file input. For example:

```
CLUSTER=cl1
command --stdin <<-SCRIPT
    cluster="$CLUSTER"
SCRIPT
```

If you do not quote the delimiter of a `<<here-document` then all of its contents are treated almost exactly like they were `"`soft-quoted - *except* that `"`double-quotes themselves are not treated specially. And so if we run the above with `cat` instead:

```
CLUSTER=cl1
cat <<-SCRIPT
        cluster="$CLUSTER"
SCRIPT
```

...it prints...

```
cluster="cl1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [mikeserv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52934/mikeserv) wrote :

```
 CLUSTER='"cl1"'; command -p "cluster=$CLUSTER"
```

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: You are right, thank you. But, what about automation? Suppose I want read CLUSTER? I will get stuck again with the same problem: variable inside single quotes

Comment: @Moi - automation is not a big deal, though you will have to sanitize the variable of `"` characters - only the first and last should be sufficient. The real problem here is your app interpreting quotes in an arg. Interpreting a quote in an argument is almost never a good idea because a quote should only be a means of delimiting an argument - and at invocation that delimiting is handled by `\0NUL`s in every case. Probably there is a better way to pass the information you want to the app? Like a `command --'script=/path/to/some/file'` or something?