# Putting variables in cardano-wallet function in terminal

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

How to enable variables in terminal to be changeable, for example address, I would like to be able to run this function through for loop in terminal with different addresses.

[image: Variables $1, $2, $3]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use variables inside single quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178411/how-to-use-variables-inside-single-quotes)

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've already done it? Assuming shell is bash the $X labels will be expanded to whatever you pass in.

So you can wrap that call with a for loop like this:

```
# declare an array variable
declare -a arr=("element1" "element2" "element3")

# now loop through the above array
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
   #or do whatever with individual element of the array
done

#You can access them using echo "${arr[0]}", "${arr[1]}" also
```

In your case you will need to get $1, $2, $3 each loop and set them, or set them up as arrays as well and then iterate through with a counter

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-an-array-of-strings-in-bash for more examples

Comment: The problem lies in ` --data 'inside quotation marks $variable doesn't work' `

Comment: Found solution.

Answer (score 0):

Inside single quotes everything is preserved literally, without exception.

That means you have to close the quotes, insert something, and then re-enter again.

```
'before'"$variable"'after'
'before'"'"'after'
'before'\''after'
```